# How to INSERT to a column whose name is a sql keyword

Tags: sql, insert

I need a table that stores key-value pairs, so I created one with a column called "Key" and a column called "Value".

This fails:

```
insert into mykeyvalues (Key,Value) values ('FooKey', 'FooValue')
```

"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'."

Maybe I shouldn't call it "Key", but I just wonder if it is possible to work with a column whose name is a sql keyword?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can surround column names like that with [ ] brackets. Therefore:

```
insert into mykeyvalues ([Key],[Value]) values ('FooKey', 'FooValue')
```

Comment: What if you were getting the value "key" from Java and could not manually put brackets around it. Then what would you do?

Answer (score 16):

Use either backticks (`) or double quotes (") around the identifiers in your query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO mykeyvalues ("Key", "Value") values ('FooKey', 'FooValue')
```

But in the long-run, this just reduces portability. It's easier to use a different name.

Comment: Actually, I believe that your example is ANSI SQL standard-conformant.

Comment: Yes, but real-life DBs often don't respect ANSI -- e.g. one wants double quotes, another one wants brackets, yet another wants backticks, etc, etc -- one headache after the other:-(

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure whether John's answer or this one should be the accepted answer. Both works like a charm.

Comment: this one should be the correct answer, it's T-SQL and not only MS-SQL, so it will work with almost all SQL queries and not only queries running on Microsoft SQL Server...

Comment: It assumes SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER ON for MS SQL. ANSI or not, using " is confusing and hard for readability if you only us MS SQL.