# SQL Add column name keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

Im trying to Add Columns to a table using a for loop in php, where each Column name is a value from an array

```
for($i=0; $i<count($column); $i++){
    query("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN ".$column[$i]." int(3) DEFAULT 0");
}
```

It works for all column names, but when it comes to the column name 'For' I get this error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near 'For int(3) DEFAULT 0'
```

Im assuming the error is because the column name is a keyword, as al the other values in the array $columns work fine.

Any suggestions how I can add a Column name 'For' or any other SQL keyword in a table?
Any feedback is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FOR` is a reserved word.  Use backticks or change the name.  The list of reserved words is here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html.

Comment: And how does the final SQL statement look?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff using bacticks worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tony surrounding the column name with brackets didn't work, I assume this only works for selecting and inserting from column, not adding column

Comment: @MattScottGibbs - In your case you need to use quotes (see the answer by James Skidmore in the linked the question) or better still, _don't use reserved words_ as field names. I would say that a field simply called `For` is not very descriptive, can you add additional words to improve the name and avoid the problem? I've retracted the close vote, as you say you are trying to create a new field, not insert data.

Comment: The only reason I have columns that could potentially be named after keywords, is because I'm creating columns based on user input. So if a user wants a column named 'For' or 'Where' for example I would have no control over it, I just need to make sure the column can be created.

Comment: This question is not special to PHP, it is a common request in SQL. See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/928932/70157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to INSERT to a column whose name is a sql keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928926/how-to-insert-to-a-column-whose-name-is-a-sql-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @GordonLinoff

Altered the query adding backticks around the column name

```
query("ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN `".$column[$i]."` int(3) DEFAULT 0");
```